# Running an animation using JCreator

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, jcreator

I wrote this program which animates a red rectangle, using JCreator, I am finding difficulty in running the annimation, does anybody have any suggestions?

This is the program which animates the rectangle:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Tutorial extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
    int x = 0 , velX = 2;
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(x, 30, 50, 30);

    tm.start();
} 

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    x = x + velX;
    repaint();
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you elaborate what problem you getting?

Comment: I dont know how im going to run this program and see the the rectangle moving, I already tried running it in a main method, but i didn't succeed

Comment: You don't actually have a main method in the code you provided...